# Implementing 3D Shader to 2D Object with Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt5, shader

I am trying to implement the following shader from here: 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68401/how-can-i-draw-outlines-around-3d-models

my base is a 2D Image that has preapplied shaders.

I was unsure how to apply this

```
glDrawBuffer( GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 );
Vec3f clearVec( 0.0, 0.0, -1.0f );
// from normalized vector to rgb color; from [-1,1] to [0,1]
clearVec = (clearVec + Vec3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)) * 0.5f;
glClearColor( clearVec.x, clearVec.y, clearVec.z, 0.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
```

So I didn't, this is what my QML code looks like:

```
    ShaderEffect {
    id: outline
    anchors.fill: swirls
    visible: true
    property variant source: swirls
    //property variant source: mascot
    // first render target from the first pass
    property variant uTexColor: swirls
    // second render target from the first pass
    property variant uTexNormals: swirls
    property variant uResolution: Qt.vector2d(960, 640) //screen resolution
    property variant delta: Qt.size(0.1 / width, 0.2 / height)
    fragmentShader: "qrc:effects/shaders/outline.frag"
    layer.enabled: true
    layer.effect: OpacityMask {
        maskSource: swirls
    }
}
```

I don't know much about normal diffuse maps and have no idea what

```
in vec2 fsInUV;
```

is which seems to be important to getting this to work. I am trying to create sprite like outlines around a circle I have made with opacity mask + shaders (it's animated to look like water with shaders)

The original user for the shaders is inactive and I'm not familiar with how QML implements Shaders, as I'm very unfamiliar with Shaders in general.

Comment: I can understand the code and what it's doing, I just don't know how to get fsUVIn, if the second part of the code even applies since I'm rendering in a scene, and if my model even has a diffuse map because it's 2D and if so how to pass the property

Comment: Perhaps your question should be - "How to implement Image outline using shaders".